# Javac в Java 10

Tags: ant, javac, java-10

В Apache Ant скрипте для Java 8 использую следующую строчку:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" destdir="${build.bin}" compiler="javac1.8"
debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" />
```

Решил проект перенести на Java 10. Изменил спецификацию в скрипте на новую версию:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" destdir="${build.bin}" compiler="javac10+" 
debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="false" source="10" target="10" />
```

Но при компиляции пакета на этой строке выдаёт сообщение:

> build.xml:65: Class not found: javac10+

Проверку на наличие соответствующей версии Java до начала компиляции проходит успешно:

```
<target name="check" description="Check requirements.">
    <echo message="Verification of your JDK version."/>
    <available classname="java.util.stream.Stream" property="JDK10+.present" />
    <fail unless="JDK10+.present" message="Java 10 is required, but your version is Java ${ant.java.version}. Install latest JDK." />
</target>
```

Подскажите, где я ошибся и как должна выглядеть строка `<javac/>` для Java 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно обновить `ant` до новой версии, так как поддержка `javac10+` [появилась](https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/RELEASE-NOTES-1.10.2.html) в версии `1.10.2`

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, в Eclipse Ant был 1.10.1 версии.